# Depth and width of ResNet152

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, resnet

I would like to know width and depth of model if I Instantiate the ResNet152 architecture like below:

```
tf.keras.applications.ResNet152(
    include_top=True, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, input_shape=None,
    pooling=None, classes=1000, **kwargs
)
```

Because I read in this [paper](https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/papers/2006.10029/) that

> We can see that increasing width and depth, as well as using SK, all improve the performance...

> We also note that ResNet-152 (3×+SK) is only marginally better than ResNet-152 (2×+SK), though the parameter size is almost doubled, suggesting that the benefits of width may have plateaued.

Comment: By depth, I guess you mean the number of layers? And what is width? Please edit & update your post to clarify.

Comment: I update my question to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

Use `model.summary()`

Sample:

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet101(
    include_top=True,
    weights="imagenet",
    input_tensor=None,
    input_shape=None,
    pooling=None,
    classes=1000,
)
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "resnet101"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 224, 224, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_pad (ZeroPadding2D)       (None, 230, 230, 3)  0           input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_conv (Conv2D)             (None, 112, 112, 64) 9472        conv1_pad[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_bn (BatchNormalization)   (None, 112, 112, 64) 256         conv1_conv[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_relu (Activation)         (None, 112, 112, 64) 0           conv1_bn[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool1_pad (ZeroPadding2D)       (None, 114, 114, 64) 0           conv1_relu[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool1_pool (MaxPooling2D)       (None, 56, 56, 64)   0           pool1_pad[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_block1_1_conv (Conv2D)    (None, 56, 56, 64)   4160        pool1_pool[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_block1_1_bn (BatchNormali (None, 56, 56, 64)   256         conv2_block1_1_conv[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_block1_1_relu (Activation (None, 56, 56, 64)   0           conv2_block1_1_bn[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_block1_add (Add)          (None, 56, 56, 256)  0           conv2_block1_0_bn[0][0]    
      
****************[Output Truncated]********************

conv5_block3_2_conv (Conv2D)    (None, 7, 7, 512)    2359808     conv5_block3_1_relu[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_block3_2_bn (BatchNormali (None, 7, 7, 512)    2048        conv5_block3_2_conv[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_block3_2_relu (Activation (None, 7, 7, 512)    0           conv5_block3_2_bn[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_block3_3_conv (Conv2D)    (None, 7, 7, 2048)   1050624     conv5_block3_2_relu[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_block3_3_bn (BatchNormali (None, 7, 7, 2048)   8192        conv5_block3_3_conv[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_block3_add (Add)          (None, 7, 7, 2048)   0           conv5_block2_out[0][0]           
                                                                 conv5_block3_3_bn[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_block3_out (Activation)   (None, 7, 7, 2048)   0           conv5_block3_add[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
avg_pool (GlobalAveragePooling2 (None, 2048)         0           conv5_block3_out[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
predictions (Dense)             (None, 1000)         2049000     avg_pool[0][0]                   
==================================================================================================
Total params: 44,707,176
Trainable params: 44,601,832
Non-trainable params: 105,344
```

Comment: ,I do this, and after that !!